# How to set a iput-object boolean to true in Smali?

Tags: java, android, boolean, apk, smali

I'm trying to edit a smali file of a decompiled Android APK I (legally) have. I can't figure out how to make this boolean be always true:

```
.method public setValid(Ljava/lang/Boolean;)V
    .locals 0

    .line 34
    iput-object p1, p0, Ltr/net/tbc/api/entity/GoalValidity;->valid:Ljava/lang/Boolean;

    return-void
.end method
```

and/or this one:

```
.method public getValid()Ljava/lang/Boolean;
    .locals 1

    .line 30
    iget-object v0, p0, Ltr/net/tbc/api/entity/GoalValidity;->valid:Ljava/lang/Boolean;

    return-object v0
.end method
```

Thanks so much for anyone helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put `sget-object p1, Ljava/lang/Boolean;->FALSE:Ljava/lang/Boolean;` before the iput-object instruction.

Or, replace the iget-object instruction with `sget-object v0, Ljava/lang/Boolean;->FALSE:Ljava/lang/Boolean;`

Comment: thank you! the boolean had to be true, but the code worked flawlessly by changing that. :)

Comment: @lol7344 Hello, It's an old post, but I hope you could still remember. I was confused by your comment, did you use ->TRUE or ->FALSE? You wanted to turns the value to be always true right?

Comment: @user516076 i wanted it to be always true iirc, i just swapped the answer's FALSE to TRUE but the code itself was correct.